# external font is not preserved in fusioncharts client export

Tags: fonts, export, fusioncharts

i am using fusioncharts for drawing charts in my app. while fusioncharts has nice exporting features (i use client exporting) also shows font in the app page correctly, but while exporting it forgets the specified font and exports with some default font. the best i could do was using Arial or Tahoma which work correctly but i couldn't use any other external font.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the custom font in your exported file you need to export options as true globally, here is a snippet below :

```
FusionCharts.options.export.useCanvas = "true"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/02cwjv8s/1/

Comment: thanks, it seems that it works perfectly! could you tell me how to implement it in php? (php wrapper of fusioncharts)

Comment: i changed fusioncharts.php file and added your code there, and it worked!!! thanks a lot.